# HttpClient.PostAsync: API is returning missing parameter

Tags: c#, .net, http-post, dotnet-httpclient

I am trying to do a post with HttpClient to a standard REST API. The post method I am targeting requires two key/value pairs, name and size. When I perform the post using the code below, the API returns the error "Required keys missing: size." However, I've clearly added it to the FormUrlEncodedContent.

I'm wondering if there is an encoding issue, or if I am using one of wrong [types of HttpContent](https://monkeyweekend.wordpress.com/2014/10/23/how-to-send-text-json-or-files-using-httpclient-postasync/).

```
public async Task<OHDrive> Create(OHDrive drive)
{
    string json = "";
    var values = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    //name and size are required
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(drive.Name) || drive.Size == 0)
        throw new Exception("Name and Size are required for drive creation");

    values["name"] = drive.Name;
    values["size"] = drive.Size.ToString();
    if (drive.UserID != null)
        values["user"] = drive.UserID;
    if (drive.Encryption != null)
        values["encryption:cipher"] = drive.Encryption;

    var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);

    using (HttpClient client = OHUtilities.CreateClient(userID, secretKey))
    {
        var url = urlBase + "create";
        var response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
        json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }

    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OHDrive>(json);
}
```

Update:

I tried switching the order of the key/value pairs, like this:

```
values["size"] = drive.Size.ToString();
values["name"] = drive.Name;
```

I then got the opposite error message: "Required keys missing: name." It's like the API is not seeing the second param for some reason. I checked the request in Fiddler and everything appears to be correct.

Comment: Unless you for some reason believe that your problem is _due_ to the use of the asynchronous nature of the `PostAsync()` call, please do not tag your question with the [tag:async-await] tag. Please _do_ provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces your problem.

Comment: Have you tried to use Fiddler to check what is the actual HTTP request being sent?

Comment: @ovolko Good suggestion. I will try that. I couldn't see the actual content when in debug.

Comment: You can also use Postman to make sure the API is returning what you expect given the correct parameters.

Comment: Do you mean that `Post` works but `PostAsync` doesn't?

Comment: As far as I can see you are making the POST request correctly with HttpClient.  And that's the right HttpContent type to use.  Can you point us to the API docs?

Comment: @DarrelMiller After reading through the [API docs](http://openhosting.com/api/) again, I realized it expects either "text/plain" or "application/json". FormURLEncodedContent sets the content type to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". I updated my code to post a json string and now it is working correctly.